# Как заполнить ArrayList при помощи IntStream

Tags: java, коллекции, потоки-данных, java-stream

Я создаю список обьектов через for, прохожу определенное кол-во раз и каждый раз создаю обьект и добавляю его в список, как мне переделать этот метод с использованием IntStream?

```
     List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<Post>();
        for (int i = 0; i<postsQuantity;i++){
                Post post = new Post.PostBuilder().id(i+1).build();
                postList.add(post);
        }
        return postList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return IntStream.range(0, postsQuantity)
    .map (i -> new Post.PostBuilder().id(i + 1).build())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

что-то вроде этого, не проверял в IDE